# Why are markdown bullet points separated by an extra newline?

Tags: html, github, markdown, jekyll

My markdown page contains these lines:

```
- [Section1](#section1)  
  - [Subsection1](#subsection1)
  - [Subsection2](#subsection2)
- [Section2](#section2)
- [Section3](#section3)
- [Section4](#section4)
```

The **expected** output *(assume each bullet is a hyperlink)*:

> - Section1
>
>   - Subsection1
>   - Subsection2
> - Section2
> - Section3
> - Section4

The **actual** output *(assume each bullet is a hyperlink)*:

> - Section1
>
>   - Subsection1
>   - Subsection2
> - Section2
> - Section3
> - Section4

I don't know why Github/Jekyll server doesn't generate the *expected* output.

When I viewed the source in the browser (Chrome), I found this (which is **not** expected):

```
<ul>
<li>
<p><a href='#section1'>Section1</a></p>

<ul>
<li><a href='#subsection1'>Subsection1</a></li>

<li><a href='#subsection2'>Subsection2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<p><a href='#section2'>Section2</a></p>
</li>

<li>
<p><a href='#section3'>Section3</a></p>
</li>

<li>
<p><a href='#section4'>Section4</a></p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Why do I see `<p>` tags here? Something wrong with the generator or my markdown code?

How should I fix it?

Comment: Your MarkDown code is fine. I checked it in both [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) and the [Markdown Dingus](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus) and it generates the expected code. It must be something wrong on Github/Jekyll.

Comment: In what cases it might possibly generate the output with extra lines? Certain combination of whitespaces (which is otherwise *invisible* in the code) might effect the output?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see that there are two trailing spaces on the first line of your Markdown source. In the Dingus, this causes a `<br />` element to be inserted before the second `<ul>`. Try it in the Dingus yourself with and without those two spaces. However, the `<br />` doesn't seem to affect the rendered HTML output - not like the `<p>` tag that you're getting on Github.

Comment: I was wondering if `<p>` could be one possible output for a mistake in the markdown source. If `<p>` is never a possibility no matter what, then surely there is a bug in Github generator.

Comment: Which markdown engine are you using?

Comment: @RobertKenny: I was using the engine used by Github (i.e my the html pages are generated by the engine at github)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just run a few tests and it looks like it is the markdown processing engine that is causing the issue.

- With the Maruku markdown engine the blank lines are added.
- With the redcarpet markdown engine no additional lines are added.
- With the kramdown markdown engine no additional lines are added.

(Can't test with rdiscount as it doesn't install on Windows)

Comment: Certainly for GitHub pages https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages you can override and use RDiscount by changing the settings in _config.yml

Comment: That is a great information. Thanks a lot. Accepted the answer. :-)